# Add check box result together to make a binary number

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get my checkbox results placed into a variable as a binary number so I can compare it with another variable.
I have 12 checkboxes and a variable from a database which needs to compare with the result of the 12 checkboxed.
Example variable from database could be 110010111001 and so if the combination of the check boxes result in the same 110010111001 then something will happen.

I have tried adding the checkbox results as shown below but this will just add up the results

```
<ul id="cat_list">
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="motorhome" name="catSelect">Motorhome</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="caravan"  name="catSelect">Caravan</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="tent"  name="catSelect">Tent</li>
</ul>

$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#cat_list').click(function () {
         let motorhomeSelect = $('input[id="motorhome"]').prop('checked');
         let caravanSelect = $('input[id="caravan"]').prop('checked');
         let checkBinary = motorhomeSelect + caravanSelect;
         console.log(checkBinary);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code to generate the binary code everytime when we change/click on the check box.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="cat_list">
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="motorhome" name="catSelect">Motorhome</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="caravan"  name="catSelect">Caravan</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="tent"  name="catSelect">Tent</li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#cat_list input').change(function () {
       var binaryNum = '';
        $.each($("#cat_list input"),function(){
          binaryNum +=$(this).prop('checked') ? '1' : '0';
        });
        console.log("Final Binary number ",binaryNum)
      });
});
```

**Codepen** - https://codepen.io/askannan/pen/yLaBpeG

Comment: Great this works, will have to study this work out how this works. Thank you